# Telerik Report - how to hide panels if table/list is empty

Tags: telerik-reporting

I am working on Telerik Reporting and I need to hide panels when the list I use by ObjectDataSource is empty. How can I handle it?
Those blue are panels, and just below the lists. But they are not together, do I have to connect them by something like subreport?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will probably be able to solve this with Conditional Formatting. Create a new conditional formatting rule for the panel you want to hide. For the rule's filter you can use a Count() function on one of the fields in your data source and check if the result is 0. In other words the rule will only apply in cases where you  have 0 records:

[image]

Then for the style of this rule open the "Style builder..." and uncheck "visible" under the layout section:

[image]

Hope this helps.